# Direct call User defined function in Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have in model.store my user defined function, but i can't import in "Function Import".
I tryed to use this syntax:

```
public class dbFunction
{
    [EdmFunction("MyModel.Store", "FN_GETPARVALUE")]
    public static string FN_GETPARVALUE(decimal ditta, string par, string retIfNull)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls are not supported.");
    }
}
```

but I can't call directly like this:

```
CommonRepository pr = new CommonRepository();
var test = pr.parametriDittaGetValue(Near_UserDitta, "PRODGESCOL", "");
```

How can I resolve my Problem?
Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `FN_GETPARVALUE`, not `parametriDittaGetValue`?

Comment: No, because, I don't see my function on Function import. I only see my user defined function in model.store. When i try to `Add Fuction Import`, I don't see function name to select.